# Multiple modules , single instance of a class - Python

Tags: python

I have two modules misc.py and main.py and would like to define all classes present in misc.py in main.py.

Below is the code

```
#misc.py

class dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dummyPrint(self):
        print "Welcome to python"

#main.py

 import misc
 dummyObj = dummy()
 dummyObj.dummyPrint()
```

Is this the right way to go ? I do not see any output i.e., Welcome to python

```
$python misc_main.py misc.py
```

EDIT: I added the statement from misc import dummy and i am getting the following error

```
$python misc_main.py main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "misc_main.py", line 5, in <module>
dummyObj =  dummmy()
NameError: name 'dummmy' is not defined
```

Comment: `from misc import dummy`

Answer (score 5):

When you do the following command, you are calling `misc_main.py` from the interpreter with `misc.py` as an argument.

```
python misc_main.py misc.py
```

Since `misc_main` is not reading command line arguments, this is equivalent to

```
python misc_main.py
```

I am surprised that you do not get errors, in either case. You need to import the actual class if you want to get output.

```
from  misc import dummy

dummyObj = dummy()
dummyObj.dummyPrint()
```

Note, I am assuming your main file is actually in called `misc_main.py` rather than `main.py` as you have stated in your question. Otherwise you are not invoking the correct file.